# Расчет колонки из значений других колонок

Tags: база-данных

Как посчитать значение в колонке используя даные из других колонок типа нумерик в одной таблице?

Comment: Не надо считать значения в колонках. какой смысл хранить то, что можно посчитать. но если очень хочется то в некоторых СУБД есть расчетные колонки. Но если они есть - то это особенности конкретных баз, а какая именно у вас вы не указали

Comment: Поясните вопрос или покажите чего хотите добиться